# Is the Casimir effect also present between two event horizons?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, casimir-effect

A follow-up to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100523/6292):

> Is the Casimir effect also present between two event horizons?

Comment: can you really believe that two event horizons can get close enough before the holes absorbing each other to manifest a Casimir effect which appears at distances of neutral surfaces densely packed in a solid, ~10^23 molecules , with an event horizon that even if statistically neutral everything moves towards the singularity and the densities are minimal?

Comment: If you are asking whether the vacuum "sea" exists then yes, it exists (Hawking radiation ) , but certainly not measurable by a Casimir type of effect.

Comment: @annav I have a pretty good imagination, so yes can believe that. Thanks for your thoughts...

Comment: Physics is not a matter of imagination but of ability to measure and quantify and model. have a look at these figures to see how small the casimir effect is and how close the two planes have to be http://inspirehep.net/record/1225058/plots?ln=en . We are talking nanometers distance between plates  for the force to be measurable.

Comment: Interesting dichotomy between "present" and "measurable" here... I tend to agree with anna, that some (many?) things in physics have to be taken on belief in theory, because they are outside of the parameter space of practical measurements. Having said that, I would like to know if anybody has a logical argument why there should be no Casimir effect between two event horizons? I can't, at the moment, come up with a reasonable handwaving argument either way.

Comment: @CuriousOne so you say that Hawking said, what I say?